# Running matplotlib in tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have this beautiful sphere I made in matplotlib. How would I go about putting it in a tkinter frame widget? It'd be nice to be able to integrate it into an existing tkinter GUI. Also is it possible to rid of the menu bar below the display? I have no need to save the output or zoom, so it's useless to me.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import  axes3d,Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig) #<-- Note the difference from your original code..

u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

x = 10 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = 10 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = 10 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))

ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,  rstride=4, cstride=4, color='lightgreen',linewidth=0)
#,antialiased=False
#cmap=cm.jet
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have a look at the examples for embedding plots in a tk GUI, it should be enough to get you started in the right direction.

[user_interfaces example code: embedding_in_tk.py](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html)

[user_interfaces example code: embedding_in_tk2.py](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk2.html)

As for removing the toolbar, it's a case of not adding it when you are embedding plots in a GUI.

> If you are using matplotlib.pyplot the
>   toolbar will be created automatically
>   for every figure. If you are writing
>   your own user interface code, you can
>   add the toolbar as a widget.