# How can i place matplotlib animation on tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, animation, canvas, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to add the animation to  tkinter canvas. How can i place matplotlib example animation on tkinter canvas either by grid or pack methods.

Comment: have a look here http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running matplotlib in tkinter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845407/running-matplotlib-in-tkinter)

Comment: @SaulloCastro : I already referred the links, but i am unable to implement the same for "imshow" and animation.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez as i am trying with imshow and funcanimation it is giving me error.

Comment: Do not import `pyplot` if you are embedding

Comment: and please show use the error you are getting

Comment: And see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391038/deleting-and-redrawing-matplotlib-animation Which is an example of embedding in QT, but the `matplotlib` side of it will be the same.

Comment: Look at the examples in the first comment, or the code in the suggested duplicate, or the example I linked to.

Comment: @tcaswell i implemented it and its working. but now how can i stop and remove the imshow..

Comment: remove it like any other tk widget

Comment: @tcaswell already did it. thanks

Comment: Please write up what you did as an answer and answer your own question

Comment: @tcaswell sure i have to add little bit features then i will add entire code and explanation

Comment: @tcaswell i am drawing imshow on canvas(figurecanvastkagg) with artistanimation im running animation and also drawing some line on the same canvas using create_line. now how can i remove the animation alone without removing the canvas and line. i can able to remove entire canvas but not animation? how can i do it?please help me

Comment: `del ani` and `im.remove()`

Comment: @tcaswell i can't able to make it work i think i am doing something wrong. i have added my new modified code in the above post please have a look at it. please clarify. how to stop or remove animation and removing image and preserving the line, canvas

Comment: I really have no idea what you are really asking at this point and this is more code than I am willing to wade through.  Please clean up and reduce your question to the _minimum_ amount of code needed to demonstrate it.

Comment: You might be better off just asking a new question, as this seems like it is in fact a different problem than you orginally asked.

Answer (score 0):

Using FigureCanvasTkAgg, like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

fb = Figure(figsize=(5, 2.5), dpi=100)
b = fb.add_subplot(111)
b.set_title('Ethernet Packet')
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fb, master=Root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=540, y=560)
b.plot(final_data)
```